# SSO Authentication for multi Active Directory domains

Tags: nginx, active-directory, kerberos, spnego

There is an **Nginx server** configured for ***SSO authenticatio with one domain*** using **krb5** and **spnego-http-auth-nginx-module**

How can you configure **dual domain** authentication?

The solution is preferably using Nginx without Apache, if available.

Config sources:

- /etc/krb5.conf

```
[logging]
 default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
 dns_lookup_realm = false
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 renew_lifetime = 7d
 forwardable = true
 rdns = false
 default_realm = DOMAIN.TEST
 default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}

[realms]
 DOMAIN.TEST = {
  kdc = domain.test
  admin_server = domain.test
 }

[domain_realm]
 .test.local = DOMAIN.TEST
 test.local = DOMAIN.TEST
```

- /etc/nginx/conf.d/django.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  django.test.local;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @backend;

        auth_gss on;
        auth_gss_realm DOMAIN.TEST;
        auth_gss_keytab /etc/krb5.keytab;
        auth_gss_service_name HTTP/django.test.local;
        auth_gss_allow_basic_fallback on;
    }

    location @backend {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-User $remote_user;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8000;
    }
}
```

Comment: In other words, it's not about nginx, it's about clients and "trust" between Kerberos realms. Without trust, duh, you would need multiple nginx instances using multiple Kerberos SPN from multiple realms.

Comment: There must be a two-way trust enabled on ADs of different domains. I don't think any changes needed at nginx level. Same SPN of nginx face url should work if the trust is configured properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Combine domains keytab files [(source)](https://lemonldap-ng.org/documentation/latest/kerberos.html)

```
ktutil
read_kt domain1.keytab
read_kt domain2.keytab
write_kt /etc/krb5_multidomain.keytab
quit
```

- Edit /etc/krb5.conf

```
[logging]
 default = FILE:/var/log/krb5libs.log
 kdc = FILE:/var/log/krb5kdc.log
 admin_server = FILE:/var/log/kadmind.log

[libdefaults]
 dns_lookup_realm = false
 ticket_lifetime = 24h
 renew_lifetime = 7d
 forwardable = true
 rdns = false
 # default_realm = DOMAIN.TEST
 # default_ccache_name = KEYRING:persistent:%{uid}

[realms]
 DOMAIN.TEST = {
  kdc = domain.test
  admin_server = domain.test
 }
 DOMAIN2.TEST = {               # append string
  kdc = domain2.test            # append string
  admin_server = domain2.test   # append string
 }                              # append string

[domain_realm]
 .test.local = DOMAIN.TEST
 test.local = DOMAIN.TEST
 .test.local = DOMAIN2.TEST       # append string
 test.local = DOMAIN2.TEST        # append string
```

- Edit /etc/nginx/conf.d/django.conf

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  django.test.local;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @backend;        

        auth_gss on;
        # auth_gss_realm DOMAIN.TEST;
        auth_gss_format_full on;                       # append string
        auth_gss_keytab /etc/krb5_multidomain.keytab;  # change string
        auth_gss_service_name HTTP/django.test.local;
        auth_gss_allow_basic_fallback on;
    }

    location @backend {
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-User $remote_user;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:8000;
    }
}
```