# Nginx kerberos auth for oracle apex HTTP Header Variable

Tags: nginx, kerberos, apex

We got "HTTP Header Variable" at Authentication Scheme in apex for kerberos auth.

```
f?p=&APP_ID.:LOGIN_DESKTOP:&APP_SESSION.:APEX_AUTHENTICATION=DB
```

On proxy server with apache the config is:

```
<Location /ords>
  AuthType Kerberos
  AuthName "Kerberos Login"
  KrbAuthRealms smth
  KrbServiceName HTTP/devgate.smth@SMTH
  Krb5KeyTab /etc/krb-keytab/keytab.spnego
  require valid-user
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REMOTE_USER} (.+)@.*
  RewriteRule . - [E=RU:%1]
  RequestHeader set SSO_USER %{RU}e
</Location>
ProxyPass /ords/ http://site.smth:8888/ords/
ProxyPassReverse /ords/ http://site.smth:8888/ords/
```

I'm trying to migrate to another server with nginx on it, but this config does not work.

```
location /ords {
auth_gss on;
auth_gss_realm SMTH;
auth_gss_keytab /etc/krb-keytab/keytab.spnego;
auth_gss_service_name HTTP/devgate.smth;
proxy_set_header Origin "" ;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header SSO_USER $remote_user;
auth_gss_format_full on;
proxy_pass http://site.smth:8888/ords/;
     }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is in your `access.log` and `error.log`?

Comment: There is nothing in error.log. When I request through the browser, I get a window with an offer to log in. "This site is asking you to sign in."

Comment: do you see headers you need for user authentication on nginx side (in *.logs)?

Comment: also this might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/64813842/973254

Comment: i see user@domain in headers, but window with an offer is here too.

Comment: ok, then try to authenticate and check if there is any difference in headers, and you may consider using `spnego-http-auth-nginx-module` module debug for your authentication `location {}` as it mentioned here: https://github.com/stnoonan/spnego-http-auth-nginx-module#debugging

Comment: Instead of Authorization: Negotiate at request to apex, i've got "GET /ords/f?p=120 HTTP/1.0
SSO_USER: user@domain
Host: site.domain:8888
Connection: close
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Authorization: Basic

Comment: try `auth_gss_allow_basic_fallback off;` to disable basic auth fallback

Comment: didn't work for me